# Passing user input to a program running through another java program

Tags: java

I am executing a java program(Test.java) using 
[**Note**:I already compiled it successfully]

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Test");
```

This goes well until Test doesn't wait for any user input...
So , for user input i used

```
BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
```

As , i don't know how much user input will Test.java take ,so i used this

```
while(p.isAlive()){
            String input=in.nextLine();
            bw.write(input);
            bw.newLine();
        }
```

But this thing isn't working.
So i just want to know why `BufferedWriter` object is not passing the input to Test.java at the instant when i do `bw.write`.Because `p.isAlive()` is always **true** due to which my program is going into infinte loop. *Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Your question might already have an answer here: [Java ProcessBuilder process waiting for input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878415/java-processbuilder-process-waiting-for-input)