# Java Processbuilder blocks on user input

Tags: java, command-line, inputstream, user-input, processbuilder

Try to figure out what I am missing (I'm still quite green on some advanced programming concepts, this is probably why I don't fully grasp my issue): I am creating an app which allows user, among other things, to open specific documents, apps or command line instructions the user types in.

Where I fail to have it working is to try to create a ProcessBuilder object to test a user-typed-in command line (macOS and Windows complaint). For a general purpose command line, e.g. `ls` (macOS) or `dir` (Windows), my code is doing fine. But when I try a command line which would require user interaction, I fail to have the output/input/error streams to properly work. I saw many related posts about issues, but none worked for me, so I hope I didn't miss out on one (sorry if I did).

Post "[Java ProcessBuilder process waiting for input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878415/java-processbuilder-process-waiting-for-input)" seemed the closest for me but I get grief on line `new Thread(new StreamGobbler("in", out, inStream)).start();` from my IDE stating that a `non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static method`.

Here is the code that I got to finally run. It simply stops at `value = is.read();` when prompt reaches the last character to display to user (EOF maybe? In may case, it asks user whether the target is a file or a folder), which I understand is because the input stream listening is not actually finished as such.

*Please note that the "xcopy" command is ONLY to illustrate my issue, the actually command line can be virtually any command line the user would enter in a field within my application.*

```
class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String command = "xcopy <file1.txt> <file2.txt>  /L /Y";
        //Following line is specific to Windows, where "cmd /c" should be
        //pre-appended to have command line to properly work.
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", command);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();
        InputStreamPass isc = new InputStreamPass(p.getInputStream());
        InputStreamPass errsc = new InputStreamPass(p.getErrorStream());
        OutputStreamExport ose = new OutputStreamExport(p.getOutputStream());
        ose.run();
        errsc.run();
        isc.run();
        int exitCode = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exit code: " + exitCode);
    } catch (SecurityException | IOException | InterruptedException | NullPointerException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}

private static class InputStreamPass implements Runnable {

    private final InputStream is;
    InputStreamPass(InputStream is) {
        this.is = is;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String message = "";
            int value = is.read();
            while (value != -1) {
                System.out.print((char)value);
                message += (char)value;
                //Code blocks at following line when reaches
                //end of prompt, waiting for user input, so value never
                //gets to be assigned the final is.read() value
                value = is.read();
            }
            System.out.println(message);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }

}//private static class InputStreamConsumer extends Thread

private static class OutputStreamExport implements Runnable {

    private final OutputStream ots;
    OutputStreamExport(OutputStream ots) {
        this.ots = ots;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ots.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }

}//private static class InputStreamConsumer extends Thread
```

And here is the output (localized form):

```
    Est-ce que file2.txt désigne un nom de fichier ou un nom de répertoire de la destination (F = fichier, R = répertoire)ÿ?
    -or rough back-translation:
    Does file2.txt relates to the filename or the foldername of the target (F = file, D = directory)?
```

Any help is more than welcome (I'm already 3 days searching and testing to no avail) :)

Comment: if you're copying files you should use `copy` instead of `xcopy`

Comment: Sure, but the "xcopy" is only for illustrating and issue when user is required interaction, not so much about the copy itself :) In other words, what if a command line is prompting for data (and therefore how to properly listen to such prompts so we can display it through the hosting app).

Comment: `xcopy` is waiting for input on its stdin, which is (the other end of) the pipe `Process.getOutputStream`. Nothing in your code ever writes anything to that stream, so `xcopy` waits forever. If you do want to write something, like in this case a line containing `D`, then put code in your program that does that.

Comment: Thanks for giving a clue, Dave. I am not quite sure to understand how to fix it though (if it can): I went a step back to Post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878415/java-processbuilder-process-waiting-for-input), where we do check whether user needs to input something through Scanner class, but I actually get the same behaviour: my program doesn't seem to be able to take whatever is output and get the Scanner to receive user input. It simply blocks on `inScanner.nextLine()` if this is the last output line and command line is waiting for user input.